# Modifying protexted image sizes: use "add_image_size()" or "update_option()"?

Tags: images, options

I'm finding conflicting info on whether it's okay to override protected WordPress image sizes (`thumbnail, medium, medium_large, and large`) with `add_image_size()`. Some docs indicate it's better to do this with `update_option ()`. Is there a practical difference between these sets of code:

```
function mytheme_image_sizes() {
  add_image_size('thumbnail', 200, 200, true);    
  add_image_size('medium', 480, 480, true); 
}
```

vs

```
function mytheme_image_sizes() {
  update_option( 'thumbnail_size_w', 200 );
  update_option( 'thumbnail_size_h', 200 );
  update_option( 'thumbnail_crop', 1 );
  update_option( 'medium_size_w', 480 );
  update_option( 'medium_size_h', 480 );
  update_option( 'medium_crop', 1 );
}
```

Note: I'm specifying these in my theme to stop admins from arbitrarily altering sizes and screwing up the post-4.4 responsive images function, and I'll probably remove the admin interface to change the image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

There is little difference, by default `crop` is set to `false`.

```
function add_image_size( $name, $width = 0, $height = 0, $crop = false ) {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $name ] = array(
        'width'  => absint( $width ),
        'height' => absint( $height ),
        'crop'   => $crop,
    );
}
```

And also during the process of evaluation

```
if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $size ] ) ) {
                $width  = intval( $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $size ]['width'] );
                $height = intval( $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $size ]['height'] );
                $crop   = ( $nocrop ) ? false : $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $size ]['crop'];
            } else {
                $height = get_option( "{$size}_size_h" );
                $width  = get_option( "{$size}_size_w" );
                $crop   = ( $nocrop ) ? false : get_option( "{$size}_crop" );
            }
```

variable `$_wp_additional_image_sizes` is took in consideration. Other then that it is very simple, options will be read from options table only if not defined.

Also please [note](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request): the database `wp_options` table is read before `functions.php` has been processed.